# folding $2^n$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics

> A rectangular strip of paper 16 units long and 1 unit wide is divided into 16 unit squares. Starting at the left end of the strip, the integers from 1 to 16 are written in order, one in each square. The strip is then folded so that the right half completely covers the left half. This action is repeated until the strip is one unit long. At this point how squares are beneath the square that has 10 written on it?
>   The order of folding 1-16 is:
>   $$1\;2\;\;3\;4\;5\;6\;7\;8\;\;9\;10\;11\;12\;13\;14\;15\;16$$
>   2 15 10 7 6 11 14 3 4 13 12 5 8 9 16 1

What is the pattern behind here? For the general case of any $2^n$, folding in this way always result in 2 at the top and 1 at the bottom in the end - but what determines the order of the numbers in between?

Comment: This appears to be rather complicated.

Comment: I had to physically cut a strip of paper, write numbers on them, fold them and figure out the order, which is not an ideal way to do it if 2^n is large

Comment: I tried to extrapolate a pattern for the general $2^n$ length case, but I felt I was going nowhere. Also trying to construct an algorithm to compute the ending position of a given square is ineffective.

Comment: To see some patterns, write 0 to 15 instead of 1 to 16 and convert the numbers to binary.

Comment: Draw a tournament bracket and fill it out in reverse: 1, 21, 2341, 27634581, etc.

Comment: so the first few is 0001 1110 1001 0110, every pair is 2's complement, but how do you jump from one pair to the next,  ie from 1110 to 1001, from 0110 to 0101?

Comment: @user526427 Check my answer, I included the pattern and an easier algorithm to follow

Answer (score 2):

We will proceed stepwise

All layers top to bottom

Step $1$:
$2$ layers

$16,15,...9$

$1,2,...8$

Step $2$:
$4$ layers

$8,7,6,5$

$9,10,11,12$

$16,15,14,13$

$1,2,3,4$

Step $3$:
$8$ layers

$4,3$

$13,14$

$12,11$

$5,6$

$8,7$

$9,10$

$16,15$

$1,2$

At this stage we have discovered a clear pattern

To fill step $3$ using step $2$,
We take the bottom left numbers (in this case $3,4$ becomes $4,3$ orientation flipped) as top most, then the pair above it $(13,14)$ and so on until we reach top left.
By this time the top of step $3$ is filled, and now for the bottom half,
Take top right pair (dont reverse, in this case $8,7$ remains $8,7$) and repeat until we reach bottom right.

Step $4$:
$16$ layers

By using the pattern discovered, I will just write down the order of the numbers
Since each layer at this stage will have only $1$ number, we only need to extract $1$ number, (in case $3$ we extracted $2$ at a time)

The order is:

$2,15,10,7,6,11,14,3,4,13,12,5,8,9,16,1$

Now to extend this algorithm to $2^n$ numbers. I will be using binary numbers here with $n$.

The order of the numbers can be constructed in the following way:
Let the binary of a number be $abcdefg.......$, where $a$ is the first binary digit

$a$ can be filled, top to bottom: in this way:

Start with $0,1$, reverse it, $1,0$, again reverse $0,1$ and so on

$b$ can be filled in the same way, start with $0101$, reverse $1010, and so on.

For $c$, start with $01010101$, reverse and repeat

Repeat this until the last column remains,

For the last column, start with $1$ and use the same pattern

Example:
For the case $n=4$

$a$ will be filled:

$0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0$

$b$ will be filled:

$0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0$

$c$ will be filled:

$0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0$

$d$ will be filled:

$1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0$

Now to make an ordered list, combine $abcd$

And we get :

$0001=1$

$1110=14$

$1001=9$

$0110=6$

$0101=5$

$1010=10$

$1101=13$

$0010=2$

$0011=3$

$1100=12$

$1011=11$

$0100=4$

$0111=7$

$1000=8$

$1111=15$

$0000=0$

And add $1$

Comment: Edit: Algorithm to find order of $2^n$ numbers